# How to Dynamically Load Javascript File into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit confused on what's required to dynamically load a JS file into the DOM.

When I include  in my HTML file, example.js will run normally.

When I include  it will add  to the DOM but not run it.

I previously believed that I had to recreate , then append() it to the  tag. I feel as if I am missing a crucial step, I just don't know what that step is.

**example.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="example.js"></script><!-- working -->
    <script src="add-example-dynamically.js"></script><!-- not working -->
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        execute( anyScriptElement ); // not working
    </script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

**add-example-dynamically.js**

```
function toExecutable( tagElement ){
    // Duplicate the provided tag as a new element in order for all tags to run the 'src' attribute after adding it to the DOM
    // Required to run: <script src=""></script>
    var newTag = document.createElement( tagElement.tagName );

    if( tagElement.hasAttributes() ){
        // Check if the tag has attributes
        for( var countAttributes = 0; countAttributes < tagElement.attributes.length; ++countAttributes ){
            var name = tagElement.attributes[ countAttributes ].name;
            var value = tagElement.attributes[ countAttributes ].value;
            newTag.setAttribute( name, value );
        }
    }
    if( tagElement.textContent ){
        // Check if the tag has content within it
        newTag.textContent = tagElement.textContent;
    }
    return newTag;
}
function execute( anyScriptElement ){
    var tag = toExecutable( anyScriptElement );
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].append( tag );
}
var theScript = document.createElement( 'script' );
theScript.src = 'example.js';
execute( theScript ); // not working
```

**Things I've tried (or a variation of)**

[error loading javascript files dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056460/error-loading-javascript-files-dynamically)

I've also been adding [.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and [.onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) to various objects without success.

**Things I don't quite yet understand**

[Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

[How do you import multiple javascript files in HTML index file without the bloat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460231/how-do-you-import-multiple-javascript-files-in-html-index-file-without-the-bloat)

[Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://cleverbeagle.com/blog/articles/tutorial-how-to-load-third-party-scripts-dynamically-in-javascript

https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

**Things I don't think solve my problem**

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

https://gomakethings.com/a-better-way-to-load-scripts-with-javascript-or-why-document-write-sucks/

**Thoughts**

I have a feeling that the right solution doesn't involve XMLHttpRequest or Promises but I'm not certain.

My repository in question: [Widgets](https://github.com/joshbalsillie/widgets)

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would help me figure out what I need to look into.

**FYI**

Native JS ideal, not interested in JQuery.

I only care about support for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari (desktop / mobile)

Comment: How does the dynamic script tag get inserted into the DOM? If you do it via `appendChild`, there shouldn't be any need for anything else, it should execute

Comment: So i get the script tags from an HTML file using XMLHttpRequest.
once the request status === 200 and readyState === 4 I use my toExecutable function on each tag before appending them to the <head> tag in example.html.

Comment: This is the reason I don't declare anyScriptElement in my example, as that part seems to be working for the most part.

I just cannot figure out why it adds the script containing the JS source to the DOM but does not execute the JS file.

Comment: Once you have the response text you want to execute as `responseText`, just do `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).textContent = responseText`, I'd think that should work

Comment: Tried the following (htmlCollection is a variable containing the head object as an html collection):

(1) domHead.textContent = theRequest.responseText; // adds html as quoted "string"

(2) domHead.textContent = htmlCollection.innerHTML; // adds html as quoted "string"

(3) domHead.textContent = htmlCollection.innerHTML.replace('"',''); // adds html as quoted "string"

Comment: I added a short script to the **add-example-dynamically.js** example that adds `<script src="example.js"></script>` to the DOM <head> tag, but does not run. Modified execute() as the head reference needed to change to work in this scenario.

Comment: so I partially solved the issue by identifying that **example.html** > `execute( anyScriptElement );` was trying to execute before `<script src="add-example-dynamically.js"></script>` loaded. Because I'm using `XMLHttpRequest();` to read external files, I tried setting `xhr.open("GET", "content.html", true);` to **false** which solved the issue with the order that content loaded into **example.html**. Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated however in various browsers (at least the way I'm using it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue was with the order that I was resolving code. It took forever to find because there was nothing inherently wrong with my code, but the sequence was wrong.

I was calling everything in the correct order, but the order that things were resolving in my network panel were incorrect.

Once I fixed the sequence that things were being loaded into the DOM, everything worked as expected.

**Fix #1**

Because my XMLHttpReqests should be asynchronous, I put all the calls into a single Javascript file so they would run synchronously.

I needed Javascript files to be loaded in the  tag before loading function calls that reference those files.

The function calls I wrapped in `window.onload = function(){}`.

Basically my final solution was for any `<script>code</script>` that I was dynamically placing in **example.html** I would wrap in `window.onload = function(){}`.

i.e. `<script>window.onload = function(){ code }</script>`

**Fix #2**

I was using the onload wrapper `window.onload = function(){}` in a location that did not make sense. Also it may have been nested within another window.onload function at one point while debugging, which probably didn't help.